# How to configure postgresql postgresql.conf listen_addresses for multiple ip addresses

Tags: postgresql

I can connect just fine to a remote postgresql server that has connection restrictions to a few IPs in the **pg_hba.conf**, but is this enough if you have `listen_addresses` set to `"*"` in the **postgresql.conf** file?

That files indicates that that parameter can take a comma separated list of ip addresses, but if i do that, I lose the ability to connect remotely.

> postgresql-8.4.9 rhel

Comment: The default convention to allow connections from any IPv4 address is `0.0.0.0`. I hope this helps you.

Comment: i want to ensure connections are only made either locally or from two remote ips. I have this successfully configured in pg_hba.conf, but what should listen_addresses be set to

Comment: Have you tried a CSV like `192.168.0.1,192.168.0.2,127.0.0.1`? In the last case, `127.0.0.1` is the RFC-compliant loopback address for your system. See this document for more info: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330.txt

Comment: Unfortunately I can not answer because that question has been closed. The answer: `listen_addresses = 'localhost, 192.168.1.10'`

Comment: And how the heck is this question "off topic"

Comment: @chrismarx because it's not strictly about *programming*. You should have asked it on another StackExchange site (e.g. http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/).

Comment: @Matthieu So should this question be moved then? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318460/how-to-move-a-question-to-another-site

Comment: @chrismarx too late ;) There are people here who want to have a clear disctinction between *programming*, *configuration*, *administration*, etc. Each topic has it own stackexchange site where you're supposed to find better experts than (i.e. "ask the right guys"). It makes senses because SO is not a general-purpose Q&A site. But OTOH most people on SO are also cross-competent so it also makes sense to ask the biggest community (SO vs. DBA). In the end it's just a human perspective; and given the number of upvotes and favorites your question has, leaving it here is probably the best :)

Comment: See similar Questions on the DBA Stack Exchange: [*Can listen_addresses really be set to a list?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48372/19079) and [*Can `listen_addresses` system configuration setting in Postgres stop pre-authentication exploits?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220931/19079) and [*Howto disable Postgres listening on TCP?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/52306/19079)

Comment: According to this: https://www.dbrnd.com/2018/04/postgresql-set-listen_addresses-for-multiple-host-addresses/, you can do it like that: `listen_addresses = '192.168.0.10, localhost, 192.168.1.8'`.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

[listen_addresses](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html) controls which IPs the server will answer on, not which IPs the server will permit connections to authenticate from. It's entirely reasonable and normal to use `listen_addresses '*'` so the server will accept incoming connections on any ip assigned to an interface on the postgresql server host, while using [pg_hba.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) to control access at a finer grained level for which IPs the server will accept logins from for specific databases and users.

Comment: ok, thats what I wanted to know, makes the issue of getting the comma separated list in there moot. thanks!

Comment: Edited to make it more explicit that `pg_hba.conf` controls *login*. The server still accepts the TCP/IP connections on any listening interface and converses with the connecting client. It just quickly concludes that the client isn't from a permitted IP range and closes the connection. This means among other things that pre-auth exploits could work with `pg_hba` exclusion but not if Pg simply wasn't listening on the interface the exploit came in on. Firewall rules, not `listen_addresses`, are the answer to that.

Comment: This solution worked for me on postgres 9.1. Thanks @CraigRinger

Comment: @CraigRinger This is still not clear to me, with the pronouns in your comment confusing me. Are you saying that pre-auth exploits are possible despite `listen_addresses` or despite `pg_hba`? In other words, the Postgres server engages the client as part of discerning the `listen_addresses` rule or does the `listen_addresses` rule prevent any server-client engagement?

Comment: @BasilBourque `listen_addresses` will work; nobody can connect even to pre-auth on an interface Pg doesn't listen on. *But* it has practical issues - it doesn't work if your IP changes, it doesn't work well on interfaces that may go up and down, etc. In practice I recommend limiting `listen_addresses` to localhost if you want a localhost-only server; otherwise, set it to `*` and use firewall rules to control which hosts can make TCP connections in a finer grained, interface-status-independent way. There's nothing wrong with using listen_addresses as a backstop if you have static ifaces.

Comment: @CraigRinger I believe this is an important enough topic to warrant its own specific Question, so I posted on the DBA Stack Exchange, [*Can `listen_addresses` system configuration setting in Postgres stop pre-authentication exploits?*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/220931/19079). Perhaps you would be willing to provide a Answer there.

Comment: `/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf` is the place to add `listen_addresses ` on Ubuntu

Comment: the path has been updated to `/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf`

Answer (score 8):

Setting listen_addresses to '*' is normal, as dbenhur points out. Also you can use tools such as iptables to deny access to the port apart from certain remote IPs. You can even do both: redundancy in security is not necessarily a bad thing (although, relying on IP address security isn't so good).

Comment: yeah, there is already ip based firewalls in place, just trying to make sure everything is configured as best it can be-