# postgres ip difference between pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf

Tags: security, postgresql

(I have a basic understanding of networking)

So I read in another post that explains that listen_addresses just involves an extra layer of security before the login: [How to configure postgresql postgresql.conf listen_addresses for multiple ip addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764126/how-to-configure-postgresql-postgresql-conf-listen-addresses-for-multiple-ip-add)

**But what I want to know is why listen_address doesn't have to be put in CIDR format for the ips you put in there.**

in `pg_hba.conf` it's `##.##.##.##/##` for CIDR format. So why does `postgresql.conf`'s `listen_addresses` use just the ip and without the subnet mask? (and also, I put my public ip address for both but access isn't allowed if I put it in `listen_address` which means...?

Side question (maybe for subnet):
amazon ec2 doesn't let me use my public ip address/24, it has to be /32 (saying the size is too small) but i put /24 in `pg_hba.conf` so clearly it's valid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot listen to a CIDR range in any OS I know of. Essentially, what happens is that `listen_addresses` is matched to one or more IP interfaces by the host OS, which binds PostgreSQL's listening socket(s) to those interfaces.

`listen_addresses` controls what network interfaces PostgreSQL can accept connections on, not what clients can connect to PostgreSQL.

In the case of EC2, `listen_addresses` cannot contain your public IP because it is not a local interface on the host. You must listen on the actual network interface, which for EC2 is usually a 10.x.x.x private IP. In practice there's no point setting `listen_addresses` to anything except `*` on EC2 unless you're using VPC and have added multiple interfaces to your host connected to different subnets.

Comment: ahhh, thank you. i was guessing that i would have to use private ip address but based on that link i posted, i was thinking it would make more sense that the connection would route to the postgresql.conf before the pg_hba.conf (since pg_hba.conf is literally logging them in, it makes sense to me that any security check would happen before that meaning private before public check wouldn't make sense)

Comment: also, any explanation on my side question? regarding subnets, i thought whether /24 or /32, it's restricted to a different subnet so i don't see why it has to be /32

Comment: @dtc Because it just doesn't make sense to listen to a subnet. You can listen to the wildcard `*` meaning all addresses on the local host, or a specific address list. `/32` is exactly one host address, and is the only form that makes any sense when listening. It's like asking "why can't I set my Ethernet interface's IP address to 10.1.1.4/24" ... you can't, it doesn't make sense. You can set it to 10.1.1.4 and specify that it's on a network that uses /24 subnet, but the address you've specified is still 10.1.1.4 with no mask, ie /32 .

Comment: @dtc Your fundamental confusion is that `pg_hba.conf` is about the *remote* (client) address, and `listen_addresses` are about on the *local* address(es) Pg listens to.

Comment: alright, thanks. i think my main confusion might be about the difference between public and private ip/subnet masks but ill try to look that up myself