# Access host database from a docker container

Tags: docker

If I have a mysql database running on some host machine, and that host is also running a docker container: How would I access the mysql database from within the docker container that is running on the host?.

For instance, is there a way to publish a hosts port to the container (the inverse of what docker run -p does)?

Comment: If the MySQL server is listening on a port, couldn't the container just connect to the host on that port like any other internet connection?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

There are several long standing discussions about how to do this in a consistent, well understood and portable way. No complete resolution but I'll link you to the discussions below.

In any event you many want to try using the --add-host option to docker run to add the ip address of the host into the container's /etc/host file. From there it's trivial to connect to the host on any required port:

> **Adding entries to a container hosts file**
>
> You can add other hosts into a container's /etc/hosts file by using
>   one or more --add-host flags. This example adds a static address for a
>   host named docker:
>
> ```
>  $ docker run --add-host=docker:10.180.0.1 --rm -it debian
>     $$ ping docker
>     PING docker (10.180.0.1): 48 data bytes
>     56 bytes from 10.180.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=254 time=7.600 ms
>     56 bytes from 10.180.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=254 time=30.705 ms
>     ^C--- docker ping statistics ---
>     2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
>     round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 7.600/19.152/30.705/11.553 ms
> ```
>
> Note: Sometimes you need to connect to the Docker host, which means
>   getting the IP address of the host. You can use the following shell
>   commands to simplify this process:
>
> ```
>  $ alias hostip="ip route show 0.0.0.0/0 | grep -Eo 'via \S+' | awk '{ print $2 }'"
>  $ docker run  --add-host=docker:$(hostip) --rm -it debian
> ```

Documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/

Discussions on accessing host from container:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1143

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10023

Comment: Will it be also working behind a NGINX reverse proxy??

Answer (score 197):

From the 18.03 docs:

> I want to connect from a container to a service on the host
>
> The host has a changing IP address (or none if you have no network access). From 18.03 onwards our recommendation is to connect to the special DNS name `host.docker.internal`, which resolves to the internal IP address used by the host.
>
> The gateway is also reachable as `gateway.docker.internal`.

EXAMPLE:
Here's what I use for my MySQL connection string inside my container to access the MySQL instance on my host:

```
mysql://host.docker.internal:3306/my_awesome_database
```

Comment: Just as hint: this does only work for Mac and Win so far

Comment: Upvote.  Not just because of the answer, but because you should HOW to use it with an example.

Comment: Still no linux support as @flp wrote, for those curious. Here is the [github issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264).

Comment: This is my connection string in .NET , it cannot find database from docker "server=gateway.docker.internal;user=root;database=mydb;port=3306;password="

tried also with "host.docker.internal"

Comment: Still no doesn't work with Linux host machines!

Answer (score 49):

Use **host.docker.internal** from Docker 18.03 onwards.

Comment: how ? can you give an example of how to use it ?

Comment: Why don't you run a dockerized mysql?

Comment: does not work for me at `Docker version 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24`

Comment: @IgorDeOliveiraSá imagine following scenario, on dev environment you have some database that listens to 127.0.0.1:3306 on production env you have database listening to 127.0.0.1:3306, locally it's local db, production it's proxy to cloud, you have to either dockerise mysql locally and and for production find another solution, or you can just connect from docker to port, it will work for both cases

Comment: __docker.for.mac.localhost__ works for me on `18.03.1-ce-mac65`

Comment: replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal `

Answer (score 44):

From Docker 17.06 onwards, a special Mac-only DNS name is available in docker containers that resolves to the IP address of the host. It is:

**docker.for.mac.localhost**

The documentation is here:
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#httphttps-proxy-support

Comment: `docker.for.mac.host.internal` from `Docker 17.12.0 ce` onwards. https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/release-notes/#docker-community-edition-17120-ce-mac46-2018-01-09-stable

Comment: `docker.for.mac.localhost ` works on `18.03.1-ce-mac65`

Answer (score 35):

Other answers did not work well for me. My container could not resolve host ip using *host.docker.internal*. There are two ways

1. Sharing host network --net=host:

   ```
   docker run -it --net=host  myimage
   ```
2. Using docker's ip address, which is usually **172.17.0.1**. 
   You can check it by calling ifconfig command and grabbing inet addr of docker interface

   ```
   user@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig
   docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:a4:a2:b2:f1  
     inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
     inet6 addr: fe80::42:a4ff:fea2:b2f1/64 Scope:Link
   ```

Once you have this ip address, you can pass it as an argument to docker run and then to application or as I do it, map the location of jdbc.properties via volume to the directory on host machine, so you can manage the file externally.

```
  docker run -it -v /host_dir/docker_jdbc_config:${jetty_base}/var/config myimage
```

NOTE: Your database might not allow external connections. In case of postgresql, you need to edit 2 files, as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/61128/configuring-the-pg-hba-conf-file-to-allow-access-from-other-servers-to-the-datab) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9764126/how-to-configure-postgresql-postgresql-conf-listen-addresses-for-multiple-ip-add):

1. Edit postgresql.conf to listen on all addresses. By default it will point to localhost.

   ```
   listen_addresses = '*'
   ```
2. Edit pg_hba.conf to allow connections from all addresses. Add on the last line:

   ```
   host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
   ```

**IMPORTANT: Last step updating database access is not recommended for production use unless you are really sure what you are doing.**

Comment: --net=host worked for me on a CI environment, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**For Linux Only**
**Case 1**:-Mysqldb running on localhost not on docker
You can fix the host Ip to connect and connect to that
ip instead of localhost.
For linux dockerhost is fixed which is **172.17.0.1**.So connect to **172.17.0.1** instead of localhost. 
**Case2**:- If the mysqldb is also running on docker then the best practice is to connect with the **docker container name** instead of IP address.

So docker-compose file should look like this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: ./.env
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=$MYSQLDB_DATABASE
    ports:
      - $MYSQLDB_LOCAL_PORT:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
producer:
     build: .
     ports:
      - '$LOCAL_PORT:$DOCKER_PORT' 
     depends_on:
         - mysqlsb
     volumes:
         - ./:/usr/src/app
```

**Now instead of an ip or localhost connect to mysqlsb**

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: mysqldb,
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Comment: Using Ubuntu 20.04. Changing the host to 172.17.0.1 does fix my problem. The container can connect to database from the host IP.

Comment: For me and my Docker Compose File - Specifying the Service that I wanted to use as my DB Host worked

Comment: Thanks so much, the solution with the docker IP 172.17.0.1 instead of localhost in your described case 1 solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

I am using:

- Mac M2 Ventura 13.6.2
- Engine: 24.0.6
- Compose: v2.23.0-desktop.1

Ran the container either way by

```bash
docker run --detach --name some-mariadb --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456  -p 3306:3306  mariadb:latest
```

OR used `docker-compose.yml`

```xml
version: "1.0"
name: "some_mariadb"
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    expose:
      - 3306
```

And successfully connected to the container simply by

```bash
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p123456
```

Answer (score 0):

There is presumably [a preferred way of doing this](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/264#issuecomment-964620100), working regardless of the host O/S.

When using docker run

```
docker run --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway
```

When using docker compose

```
services:
  myservices:
    extra_hosts:
      - host.docker.internal:host-gateway

    environments:
      - DBHOST=host.docker.internal:5432
```

This will create an entry `host.docker.internal` in `/etc/hosts`