# How to connect the docker container to remote postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am successfully able to connect the servicebot service to the postgresql running within the docker container but I want to connect the servicebot to the postgresql running in instance ie not inside docker container.

I have installed the postgresql successfully. I have set the  environment variables related to postgrsql in the docker-compose.yml as bellow. How can I make the docker-compose.yml connect to the

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  servicebot:
    image: servicebot/servicebot
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_PORT : "5432"
      POSTGRES_DB_HOST : "localhost"
      POSTGRES_DB_USER : "servicebot_user"
      POSTGRES_DB_PASSWORD : "servicebot_pass"
      POSTGRES_DB_NAME : "servicebot_user"
      PORT : "3000"
    volumes:
      - upload-data:/usr/src/app/uploads
      - environment-file:/usr/src/app/env
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
#    links:
#      - db
    ports:
      - "80:3000"
      - "443:3001"
    command: ["sh", "-c", "node /usr/src/app/bin/wait-for-it.js db 5432  && npm run-script start"]

volumes:
  upload-data:
  environment-file:
  db-data:
```

Previously I had a service named  db for postgresql and connected to it with links as  you  can  see, I have commented that out now.

I am very new to postgresql and not able to figure out the right way. I  have  tried few ways but nothing came to my success.

**Tried:**

- Adding `extra_hosts` to the ip if the instance
- Adding `host.docker.internal` instead of localhost

**Error Logs:**

> On `docker logs servicename`  It does not show anything. The service
>   stops  after 29 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is `POSTGRES_DB_HOST` pointing to "localhost", as "localhost" will be the container running your current service.

If you want to connect to a postgre running in your host (localhost) I think you can use this special value `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: so you mean i need to replace `localhost` with `host.docker.internal`

Comment: Yes you have to replace `localhost` with a valid value, that I think it's `host.docker.internal` for your purpouses.

Comment: the change is not working, same issue the container shuts down.

Comment: It may depend on your docker version. Have a look to this question's answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056522/access-host-database-from-a-docker-container

Comment: its exactly same for my docker version as you recommended but I can see people recommending to run it as `--net=host` so I tried adding the `network_mode: "host"` to my docker-compose.yml but same not issue.

Comment: Run `docker inspect <container>` and search for any error

Comment: i don't think docker inspect will  help me search for any error. Is that even possible? I am not able to check the logs as its not showing on running the logs command @Ander2

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up that if you're running `Docker` on a MAC (macOS), you need to use: `docker.for.mac.host.internal` instead.