# Accessing a Database in a Container

Tags: python, mysql, docker, mysql-connector-python

I have a python-app dockerized in a container(windows 10 for now), which connects to a MySQL8.0 DB, loads and manipulates data, converts to xml and publishes them with MQTT. Although a docker novice with some trouble understanding, i built a simple image and container for the python-app alone. Problem is, me and my team may want to place the DB inside the docker. Is it possible to insert the tables/data in our DB in a docker-container ?

There are docker-images for all DB's online but i failed to pass the DB we use with the data and the tables.
[Access host database from a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056522/access-host-database-from-a-docker-container)
I searched before and i found some interesting posts but none answer my question exactly

Here is the part of the code tha connects to db :

```
conc = mysql.connector.connect(user='root3r', password='**********', host='******',
                               database='sql_data', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
```

If the DB is inside the container, WHAT IP should i pass in the host argument ?

EDIT : Ok after many trials i used command "docker-machine ip"  and THAT IP worked for me, so my local app, managed to connect to the Dockerised-DB BUT i cannot connect from any other remote machine with the same python.app

Is docker-machine IP visible only for the docker host ?

Comment: Provide `docker run` command of your db.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/network/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using docker-compose Docker will make aa internal network between all composed containers. In this case you can pass name of the container as a host.
For example in docker-compose.yml file there are 2 containers runnning:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  api:
    image: python
  db_container_name:
    image: postgres
```

You can make a HTTP call from api to db container with something like:

````
conc = mysql.connector.connect(user='root3r',password='**********',hostst='db_container_name',database='sql_data',auth_plugin='mysql_native_password') ```
````

Comment: i used "docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" container_name_OR_id" command to get my container's IP, then i tried to connect through my python app (locally) and could not connect. Any reasons why ?

Comment: you might need to share container port with host machine port on run. Use directive -p.
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Answer (score 0):

After some experimenting, both

-docker-machine ip

AND

-adding the image name of the container (example : db)

solved the case for me.