# Airflow unable to start with mysql db backend

Tags: python, docker, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have installed Apache Airflow on docker with MySQL database backend.My OS is Windows. I am getting '*Connection refused*' error and unable to start airflow with *docker-compose up* command. The error message and docker-compose.yaml file are mentioned below. Probably there's a mistake in .yaml file but I don't understand what. Please suggest.

**Error Message**

```
airflow-airflow-webserver-1  | ERROR! Maximum number of retries (20) reached.
airflow-airflow-webserver-1  |
airflow-airflow-webserver-1  | Last check result:
airflow-airflow-webserver-1  | $ run_nc 'localhost' '3306'
airflow-airflow-webserver-1  | (UNKNOWN) [127.0.0.1] 3306 (mysql) : Connection refused
airflow-airflow-webserver-1  |  sent 0, rcvd 0
```

**docker-compose.yaml file**

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.0.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: LocalExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: mysql+mysqldb://malabi:password@localhost:3306/malabidb
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
    - ./requirements.txt:/requirements.txt
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-00000}"
  depends_on:
    mysql:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: airflow_mysql_db
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: malabidb
      MYSQL_USER: malabi
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - mysql-db-volume:/var/lib/mysql
    healthcheck:
      #test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost","-u","root","-p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"]
      test: "/usr/bin/mysql --user=root --password=root --execute \"SHOW DATABASES;\""
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always

  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    restart: always

  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}


volumes:
  mysql-db-volume:

networks:
  backend:
    driver: "bridge"
```

Comment: You are trying to connect to localhost, which is not where that database is hosted. You need to connect to wherever the database is from the container's perspective

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28058549/7867968) might have the answer you're looking for