# When setting up nocodb with docker, I want to connect to mysql running on the host

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

We are currently running nocodb using pm2.
I would like to replace it with docker and use the existing mysql data.

I want to connect to mysql on the host side from docker but I don't know how.
It seems to be caused by mysql not allowing external connections, but even after changing the setting, it failed.

Please let me know what kind of compose file would be successful.
There are several similar questions on the Github discussion, but no one seems to have been able to resolve them.

- [Installation Error · nocodb/nocodb · Discussion #3864](https://github.com/nocodb/nocodb/discussions/3864)
- [Docker nocodb Connect to Host MySQL? · nocodb/nocodb · Discussion #902](https://github.com/nocodb/nocodb/discussions/902)

I did some settings such as allowing mysql external connection based on the official docker-compose.yml,
but the connection failed and I could not start it.

- [nocodb/docker-compose/mysql/docker-compose.yml at develop · nocodb/nocodb](https://github.com/nocodb/nocodb/blob/develop/docker-compose/mysql/docker-compose.yml)
- [Access host database from a docker container - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056522/access-host-database-from-a-docker-container)
- [How to connect to the Docker host from inside a Docker container? | by Tim van Baarsen | Medium](https://medium.com/@TimvanBaarsen/how-to-connect-to-the-docker-host-from-inside-a-docker-container-112b4c71bc66)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.43, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
$ docker -v
Docker version 25.0.5, build 5dc9bcc
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what exactly you tried and _how_ "it failed" - what are the error messages you receive? What configuration did you use - which host/port did you configure in nocodb as database?